# Implementing a model written in a Predicate Calculus into ProLog, how do I start?

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence

I have four sets of algorithms that I want to set up as modules but I need all algorithms executed at the same time within each module, I'm a complete noob and have no programming experience.  I do however, know how to prove my models are decidable and have already done so (I know Applied Logic).

The models are sensory parsers.  I know how to create the state-spaces for the modules but I don't know how to program driver access into ProLog for my web cam (I have a Toshiba Satellite Laptop with a built in web cam).  I also don't know how to link the input from the web cam to the variables in the algorithms I've written.  The variables I use, when combined and identified with functions, are set to identify unknown input using a probabilistic, database search for best match after a breadth first search.  The parsers aren't holistic, which is why I want to run them either in parallel or as needed.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Can you point me to a good introductory paper about sensory grammars?

Answer (score 0):

> I also don't know how to link the
>   input from the web cam to the
>   variables in the algorithms I've
>   written.

I think the most common way for this is to use the machine learning approach: first calculate features from your video stream (like position of color blobs, optical flow, amount of green in image, whatever you like). Then you use supervised learning on labeled data to train models like HMMs, SVMs, ANNs to recognize the labels from the features. The labels are usually higher level things like faces, a smile or waving hands.

Depending on the nature of your "variables", they may already be covered on the feature-level, i.e. they can be computed from the data in a known way. If this is the case you can get away without training/learning.